# Find and Change Gem Paths on Windows

Tags: ruby, rubygems

How are the Gem Paths set in Windows 7? This is my listing:

```
    - GEM PATHS:
      - c:/jruby-1.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
      - c:/Users/biged/.gem/jruby/1.8
```

I need to delete the second entry and add an additional path as the first entry. How do I find where these are set and change them?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Gem User Guide](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3)...

```
set GEM_HOME=/home/mygemrepository
```